# Process records parallely in a BAM file

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a BAM files of different sizes like average of 20GB. The BAM file generally contain chromosome records in it. I am looking to parallel process all the chromosome records. Here is an example

BAM file will be sorted:
chr1 - 0.3 million reads/records
chr2 - 0.27 million reads/records
and so on to
chr25/chrM.

I am looking to process all these its own chromosome records parallel'y. For this I implemented producer consumer approach. Keeping the queue size as 0.1 million if I give more queue size then it will be a heap problem. So this approach is wrong.

Another approach is opening the same file multiple times for read but I see the IO performance issue and it is going sequentially. Will allowing the thread to read its own chromosome offset ranges in the BAM file will help work parallel'y?

Any suggestions to make it work parallel?

Answer (score 0):

Please consider this:

1. create a thread pool
2. read a chunk of data from file
3. start a task in your thread pool with the chunk of data
4. repeat from 2 if there is more data in file